# Как вывести даные js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Как сделать так, чтобы GetData возвращала данные с ajax запроса

```
function GetData(url){
    // var data = null;
    // $.ajax({
    //     url: url
    //   }).then(function (result) {
    //     data = result;
    //   })
    // return data;
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: url,
     });
     
     request.done(function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
     });
return data;

}
```

`<script>alert(GetData("");</script>`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax-запрос выполняется асинхронно. Следовательно, он не успеет выполниться до того момента, как GetData закончит выполняться. Выполняйте Ajax-запрос синхронно либо прокидывайте в свой callback, который будет выполняться по завершению запроса

Comment: success: function data(data){
           
            
        }